# count specific column values

Tags: pandas, count

I have the following dataframe and I would like to have the column "counter_col_x" which should "count" where column x == 8. Only column x=8 is important.

```
counter_col_x   x    y
0       8    36
0       8    36
0       8    36
0       8    36
0       8    36
nan     1    0
nan     1    1
nan     1    0
1       8    36
1       8    36
1       8    36
1       8    37
1       8    36
nan     1    0
nan     1    1
nan     1    0
nan     1    0
2       8    36
2       8    37
2       8    36
2       8    37
2       8    36
```

Thanks for any hints,

cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
df = ( df.assign(counter_col_x = df.loc[df['x'].eq(8)]
                                   .groupby(df['x'].ne(df['x'].shift())
                                                 .cumsum())
                                   .ngroup()
                                  #.reindex(index = df.index) #only if necessary
                 )
         .reindex(columns = ['counter_col_x'] + df.columns.tolist()) )
```

**or maybe better**:

```
df = ( df.join(df.loc[df['x'].eq(8)]
                 .groupby(df['x'].ne(df['x'].shift())
                                 .cumsum())
                 .ngroup()
                #.reindex(index = df.index) #only if necessary
                 .rename('counter_col_x'))
      )
```

**Output**

```
    counter_col_x  x   y
0             0.0  8  36
1             0.0  8  36
2             0.0  8  36
3             0.0  8  36
4             0.0  8  36
5             NaN  1   0
6             NaN  1   1
7             NaN  1   0
8             1.0  8  36
9             1.0  8  36
10            1.0  8  36
11            1.0  8  37
12            1.0  8  36
13            NaN  1   0
14            NaN  1   1
15            NaN  1   0
16            NaN  1   0
17            2.0  8  36
18            2.0  8  37
19            2.0  8  36
20            2.0  8  37
21            2.0  8  36
```

Comment: Question... why are you reindexing at the end?  `df.assign(counter_col_x = df[(df['x'] == 8)].groupby((df['x'] != df['x'].shift()).cumsum()).ngroup())` that should work by itself.

Comment: It's true, this is not necessary, I did it by intuition. Do you think there could be any version of pandas that needs reindex here? @ScottBoston

Comment: @ansev I don't think so, pandas has always been aligning data on indexing.